# Slow query by using CAST

Tags: mysql

I need help with a data conversion that I think it can be the problem of slow query. I'm using MySQL 5.6. In the second query below, when returning the `@MRESULT` variable, when I use the value of `@CALL_ID_DC` as a parameter, the query runs very fast. When using the `@CALL_ID_DC`, the query runs very slowly. The idCall field is a VARCHAR (255).

How should I proceed to correct this problem?

```
SET @CALL_ID_DC = (
                             SELECT DC.CallId AS idCall
                             FROM TABELA_DC DC
                             WHERE 
                                DC.Seq = 370065764
                        );

-- @CALL_ID_DC => está com valor '12345'


SET @MRESULT = (
                        SELECT C.idCall FROM TABELA_C C
                        WHERE
                            C.idCall = @CALL_ID_DC -- by using this way, query is slow
                            -- C.idCall = '12345' -- by using this way, query is fast
                        LIMIT 1
                    );
```

I've tried to cast the `@CALL_ID_DC` variable to CHAR, but it hasn't changed the query's behavior.

**[EDIT]**

```
EXPLAIN tables

TABELA_DC
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      DC      const   PRIMARY         PRIMARY     8           const   1       NULL


TABELA_C
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          C       ALL     IdCall          NULL    NULL    NULL    821609  Using where
```

Comment: User-defined variable usage converts index scan to iterational fullscan.

Comment: Does `CallId`/`idCall` names difference is not a misprint?

Comment: Yes. It's different.

Comment: I'he already solve problem. I changed `=` for `like`in the second query. Thanks

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there _may_ be an issue with datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.idCall 
INTO @MRESULT
FROM TABELA_C C,
JOIN TABELA_C DC ON C.idCall = DC.CallId
                AND DC.Seq = 370065764
/* ORDER BY something - or you'll get random record */
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The tables are in distincts databases. I can't do it. I'he already solve problem. I changed `=` for `like` in the second query. Thanks

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from your code

Comment: @wBB - `LIKE` is optimized into `=` when there are no wildcards, so I dispute your observation.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT` for each case.

Comment: I've edited my question text and put `EXPLAIN` for two tables. Thanks

Comment: @wBB Without CREATE TABEL for TABELA_C 2nd EXPLAIN tells close to nothing.